weak (?) valuative criterion for properness
In the article "On the Kodaira Dimension of the Moduli Space of Curves" by J. Harris and D. Mumford, to prove that
$\overline{H}_{k,b}$ is proper over Spec $\mathbb{C}$, the authors refer to a "weak valuative criterion for properness." I am not familiar with and cannot find a reference to a "weak valuative criterion for properness." Why "weak..."?
What I am familiar with is the "valuative criterion for properness", used, for example, to prove that the Hilbert and Quot schemes are projective.
Does this "weak..." have any mathematical meaning?

Probably they mean the "stacky" valuative criterion of properness:
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2289801/valuative-criterion-for-properness-up-to-extensions
See https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/0CL9

The answer by user @AriyanJavanpeykar is quite likely what is meant.  They may also intend the answer to the following MO question (one of many similar “folk results”), since this was already used by Deligne and Mumford in their article on properness of $\overline{M}_g$: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/493/can-the-valuative-criteria-be-checked-on-a-dense-open
